# WCF how can I avoid faulted channels if they are closed by server due to inactivity

Tags: c#, wcf, timeout, wcf-binding

My service host is configured to close connection after 10 mins

```
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
</wsHttpBinding>
```

In my client code before using service it is validated. If it is in closed/faulted state it will create a new one.

```
    public static T ValidateService<T>(ref T service) where T : class
    {
        if (service is IClientChannel)
        {
            IClientChannel channel = service as IClientChannel;
            CommunicationState state = channel.State;
            if (state == CommunicationState.Faulted || state == CommunicationState.Closed)
            {
                // thread safe logic to create new service 
            }
        }
    }
```

Problem is when channel is closed on server side and channel.State will still return Open state. After I do remote call I get faulted exception and due to `receiveTimeout`.

Is there any way to have inactivity timeout on client side? something like  `receiveTimeout="00:10:00"` on server but with few seconds less so I can nicely close a channel from client if not used and than my `ValidateService<T>` logic will create a new one if needed.

For performance reasons I do not want to create new channel for every remote call because those can be very frequent.

I would like to avoid having heart beat poller for each of my services I am using in my communication.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't avoid handling `Faulted` and `Closed` since it is always possible that some network problem or similar leads to a situation where you have to create a new `Channel`...

EDIT - as per comment:

In production I usually have a client implementation which handles certain exceptions by recreating the `Channel` and retrying... this takes care of the case you are describing and several other cases like network hickup etc.

Comment: So there is no better way of handling receiveTimeout on client side? I was thinking of having a poller on client to either do some heart beat or nicely close the channel if the last used period is long enough. Something like a receiveTimeout working on a client side.

Comment: @marek In production I usually have a client implementation which handles certain exceptions by recreating the Channel and retrying...

Comment: i was hoping there is a build in way to close unused channel from client side instead of ending up with faulted channel on client. I do understand faulted channel can happen for many other reasons but I am surprised there is not a nice way of nicely closing unused channel from client similar to receiveTimeout.

Comment: @marek let's assume there is a way to do that... then the result would be a `Channel` with `State` being `Closed`... what would that change in your code ? in absolute bestcase in the `if` you would remove `Faulted`... I don't think that would be production quality since `Faulted` could still happen because of other reasons...

Comment: @marek what you could do would be to create "client pool" similar to a "DB connection pool" and then everytime you get a "client" the "pool" would validate it first and remove/recreate it appropriately... when you return it to the "pool" the "pool" would again check for specific `State` and discard/recreate it...

Comment: I think you are right. I just have to live with the fact channel.Closed due to timeout will be handled as any other channel faulted case. Potentially I will have 100s of clients (some of them might not be active/other can be very active) so I was hoping to keep number of alive connections to minimum and I do not want to be spammed by communication errors which I do not have to see.

Thanks for your help